# Rendering a functional component as JSX breaks React render reconciliation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the users of my component to be able to pass in an object of components, and I want to allow them to use functional or class based components.

```
type InputComponents = Record<string,  React.ComponentType>
```

This allows either FC or class components but I didn't find definitive guidelines on how to render them.

```
const inputComponents = {
  a: ({ placeholder }) => ( // Functional component
    <input
      type="text"
      value={state.a}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChange={(e) => {
        const value = e.currentTarget.value;
        setState((s) => ({ ...s, a: value }));
      }}
    />
  ),
  b: InputClass // Class component
};
```

Both of the components render fine without Typescript complaining like this:

```
const A = inputComponents.a;
const B = inputComponents.b;

<A placeholder="Type something" />
<B placeholder="Type something" />
```

But this is actually misleading - **The functional one (a) will loose focus every key press**.

The only way to make the functional component not loose focus every key press is like this:

```
inputComponents.a({ placeholder: 'Type something' })
```

Typescript doesn't even consider that a valid way to render a component and yet it's the only fully working way..... it errors with "This expression is not callable." and also fails for the Class component so I have to do this:

```
// Render as JSX for class components and call as a function for FC ones...
Component.prototype.isReactComponent ? <Component placeholder={x} /> : Component({ placeholder: x })
```

You can see the problem in action here:

```js
function SomeComponent({ inputComponents }) {
  const B = inputComponents.b;
  const C = inputComponents.c;

  return (
    <div className="SomeComponent">
      <p>This FC component doesn't loose focus:</p>
      {inputComponents.a({ placeholder: 'Type something' })}
      <p>This one does:</p>
      <B placeholder="Type something" />
      <p>Rendering a class component as JSX works though:</p>
      <C placeholder="Type something" />
    </div>
  );
}

class InputClass extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ''
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.value}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        onChange={(e) => {
          this.setState({ value: e.currentTarget.value });
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    a: '',
    b: ''
  });

  const inputComponents = {
    a: ({ placeholder }) => (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={state.a}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const value = e.currentTarget.value;
          setState((s) => ({ ...s, a: value }));
        }}
      />
    ),
    b: ({ placeholder }) => (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={state.b}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const value = e.currentTarget.value;
          setState((s) => ({ ...s, b: value }));
        }}
      />
    ),
    c: InputClass
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SomeComponent inputComponents={inputComponents} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Is React broken? Or what is the correct way to handle this without relying on hacking TS errors and using internal stuff like `isReactComponent`? Thanks

Comment: Updated with demo here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new component (the function itself) on every rerender because you have `inputComponents` within the `App`. The same behaviour would happen to class component if you move class declaration to the inner scope

```
inputComponent = {
  c: class InputClass extends Component {}
}
```

To solve the problem you can move components map to the outer scope and pass `state` and `setState` as props. Or provide via context.

```js
function SomeComponent({ inputComponents, args }) {
  const B = inputComponents.b;
  const C = inputComponents.c;

  return (
    <div className="SomeComponent">
      <p>This one does:</p>
      <B placeholder="Type something" {...args} />
      <p>Rendering a class component as JSX works though:</p>
      <C placeholder="Type something" {...args} />
    </div>
  );
}


class InputClass extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ''
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.value}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        onChange={(e) => {
          this.setState({ value: e.currentTarget.value });
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

  const inputComponents = {
    b: ({ placeholder, state, setState }) => (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={state.b}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const value = e.currentTarget.value;
          setState((s) => ({ ...s, b: value }));
        }}
      />
    ),
    c: InputClass
  };


function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    a: '',
    b: ''
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SomeComponent inputComponents={inputComponents} args={{state, setState}} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is for a datagrid `filterComponents` and the users have a `filterState` object that they need to pass into another hook, so they are likely to define the components inside to access that state, but wrapping in `useMemo` won't work as the state changes each key press. Maybe I can think of a better design but I also don't want to rely on my users doing the smart things. I have a workaround by detecting and calling the FC components as functions but I find it weird that I can't call them via the normal JSX way. Anyway +1

Comment: "I have a workaround by call the FC components as functions" I'd suggest to not call it components than. Call it [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). If user wanted to use class component they could still pass it as render prop `c: (args) => <MyClassBasedComponent {...args} />`

Comment: Thanks I did it that way and it works without the hackiness